# Excel SUMIFS formula doesn't work if cell blank

Tags: worksheet-function

Here is a picture of my data:
[image: SUMIFS error]

My formula in cell K3 is `=SUMIFS(F:F,A:A,I3,C:C,J3)`

My formula in cell K4 is `=SUMIFS(F:F,A:A,I4,C:C,J4)`

Why is my value in K4, not the same as in K3?

Answer (score 0):

J4 is blank. So, SUMIFS evaluates it to 0. Meaning your criteria are E2 and 0. Thus, the result is 0 when the sum is completed.

Comment: As an addendum, OP can make it work like they want if set `J4` to this formula `=""`. Now it's seen as a blank string and not an empty cell so Excel won't treat it like a zero.